# Strophe chat send status

Tags: cordova, strophe

How to know whether a chat message has been sent successfully in Strophe？

For example

```
var reply = $msg({
    to: id + '@' + chatServerIP,
    from: uid + '@' + chatServerIP,
    type: 'chat'
}).cnode(Strophe.xmlElement('body', msg));
chatConnection.send(reply.tree());
```

how to how the reply has been sent successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get an acknowledgement of any sort if that's what you are looking for. You should get an error if it fails. Also check if your server is set up to store offline messages. Your message may be going there if the recipient is not online.

You could set up receipts to get acknowledgements http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html.